# Finding the Taylor Series for $f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$ about $a = 5$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$$ about $a=5$

So I found the polynomial, but getting it into a series is where I'm having trouble. The first two terms are positive, and then it alternates. 
The $C_n$ term is $1$ divided by some power of $2$. That power goes $0, 2, 6, 9, 14, \dots  $

Any suggestions?

I can't post images apparently, but it's

$$2 + \frac{1}{4}(x-5) - \frac{1}{64}(x-5)^2 + \frac{1}{512}(x-5)^3 - \frac{5}{16384}(x-5)^4 + \cdots$$

What I have so far:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n(x-5)^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us forget the value of $5$ and be as lazy as I am.

Let $x=y+a$ to make 
$$\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{y+(a-1)}=\sqrt{(a-1)}\,\sqrt{1+\frac{y}{a-1}}$$ Now, let $z=\frac{y}{a-1}$ and use the binomial expansion for $\sqrt{1+z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{k}z^k$. Then, replace. So, around $x=a$,
$$\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{(a-1)}\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\frac 12}{k}\left(\frac{y}{a-1}\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{\frac 12}{k}}{(a-1)^{k-\frac 12} }(x-a)^k $$

Answer (score 0):

We know that taylor expansion is given as 
\begin{equation}
 f(x) =
 f(a)+\frac {f'(a)}{1!} (x-a)+ \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+ +\frac{f''''(a)}{4!}(x-a)^4+ \cdots
\end{equation}
In your case $a=5$, so
\begin{equation}
 f(x) =
 f(5)+\frac {f'(5)}{1!} (x-5)+ \frac{f''(5)}{2!} (x-5)^2+\frac{f'''(5)}{3!}(x-5)^3+ \frac{f''''(5)}{4!}(x-5)^4+ \cdots
\end{equation}
Let's get all 4 derivatives

\begin{align}
 f'(x) &= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\\
 f''(x) &= -\dfrac{1}{4\left(x-1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\\
 f'''(x) &= \dfrac{3}{8\left(x-1\right)^\frac{5}{2}}\\
 f''''(x) &= -\dfrac{15}{16\left(x-1\right)^\frac{7}{2}}
\end{align}
Replacing for $x = a = 5$, we get
\begin{align}
 f(5) &= 2\\
 f'(5) &= \frac{1}{4}\\
 f''(5) &= -\frac{1}{32}\\
 f'''(5) &= \frac{3}{256}\\
 f''''(5) &= -\frac{15}{2048}
\end{align}
Replacing we get
\begin{equation}
 f(x) =
 2+ \frac{1}{4} (x-5) -\frac{1}{32(2)}(x-5)^2+\frac{3}{3!(256)}(x-5)^3-\frac{15}{4!(2048)}(x-5)^4+ \cdots
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
 f(x) =
 2+ \frac{1}{4} (x-5) -\frac{1}{64}(x-5)^2+\frac{1}{512}(x-5)^3-\frac{15}{4!(2048)}(x-5)^4+ \cdots
\end{equation}

---

### In General

> We notice that for $n > 2$
>   \begin{equation}
>  f^{(n)}(x) 
>  =
>  (-1)^{n+1}
>  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k+1)}{2^{n}(x-1)^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}}
> \end{equation}
>   so for $n>2$
>   \begin{equation}
>  f^{(n)}(5) 
>  =
>  (-1)^{n+1}
>  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k+1)}{2^{n}(5-1)^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}}
>   =
>  (-1)^{n+1}
>  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k+1)}{2^{n}(4)^{\frac{2n-1}{2}}}
> =
>  (-1)^{n+1}
>  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k+1)}{2^{n}(2)^{2n-1}}
> \end{equation}
>   Replacing we get
>   \begin{equation}
>  f(x) 
>  =
> 2+
> \frac{1}{4}(x-5)
> -
> \frac{1}{64}(x-5)^2
> +
>  \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}
>  (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-2} (2k+1)}{\underbrace{2^{n}(2)^{2n-1}}_{2^{3n-1}}n!}(x-5)^n
> \end{equation}

Comment: I already did that part, but thank you. Sorry if it's unclear, but I'm trying to find the series representing that polynomial. I tried doing it at the end of my OP.

Comment: i have edited @BigArsole

Comment: When n=3, the denominator is not 512. n=4, the fraction is also  incorrect. Sorry for nitpicking but I've been trying for a long time

Comment: you are definitely right, i forgot a numerator term .. let me edit

Comment: btw your lastterm 16384 is not correct as well.. should be like the one mentioned here

Comment: I meant to write 5/16384, same 15/(4!2048)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the specific closed form for the series, you need to express the $n$th derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x=5$ for all $n$.

Since $f(x)=(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, we know that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Note the change: the power on $(x-1)$ drops by 1, and you multiply on the current power.

This means the $n$th derivative of $f$, for $n>1$ is
$$\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\dotsc\left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\left(1\cdot(-1)\cdot(-3)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(-(2n-3))\right)(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}(1\cdot3\cdot\dotsc\cdot(2n-3))(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\\
&=-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n(2n-3)!!(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}-n}
\end{align*}$$
where $!!$ is the double factorial.

Now substitute $x=5$ to get $f(5)=4$, $f'(5)=1/4$, and
$$\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(5)&=-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n(2n-3)!!\cdot4^{\frac{1}{2}-n}\\
&=-2\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)^n(2n-3)!!
\end{align*}$$

Putting that into the Taylor expansion gives
$$f(x)=4+\frac{1}{4}(x-5)-2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2n-3)!!}{8^nn!}(x-5)^n$$

Note: if you really dislike the double factorial, rewrite it as
$$\begin{align*}
(2n-1)!!&=1\cdot3\cdot\dotsc\cdot(2n-1)\\
&=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\dotsc\cdot2n}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\dotsc\cdot2n}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}
\end{align*}$$